# Getting the character index for a x,y position in a NSString drawn with drawInRect

Tags: ios, nsstring

I'm currently using NSString's drawInRect to display a font. This is then being uploaded to a texture to be used by OpenGL.

Example:

```
[String drawInRect:textRect withFont:font lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap     alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
```

What I now need is a method to determine the index of the character if [x,y] were clicked. 
So if I passed in [0,0] it would return index [0]. Or [24,4] would return 5 for example.

One way to do this would be if I can get the individual bounding boxes of the glyphs drawn and iterate through them.

Or is there a better way to draw the text that would allow this sort of functionality?

Comment: It is possible to get the width and height of each of the characters used using CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters and CTFontGetBoundignRectsForGlyphs. However I haven't found a method to get the x,y of the bounding box of each character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to do this with the NSString and NSAttributedString drawing methods. I'd recommend one of three ways of making tappable text:

1) **Core Text** PRO: It's fast, it works on older versions of iOS. CON: It's got a lot of boilerplate. You'll have to create NSDictionaries of very wordy text attributes to use when creating attributed strings, then use those attributed strings inside a `drawRect:` implementation to create a `CTFrameSetter` via `CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString()`, then use the frame-setter to create a `CTFrame`, then use the `CTFrame` to draw your text. Whew! After all that, you can query the `CTFrame` (through even more complicated code) to find the index of a tapped character at a given `CGPoint`. All this is not trivial to set up.

2) **TextKit** PRO: It's much easier than Core Text. CON: It's only available on iOS 7. You can use `UITextView`, along with the methods exposed by its new properties (an `NSLayoutManager` and `NSTextContainer`), to obtain string information given a CGPoint.

3) Use **[TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel).** PRO: It's easiest of all, and works on older versions of iOS. CON: It may not provide the features you need.

Comment: Currently I use CGBitmapContextCreate to create a context pointing to a RGB buffer. I then call UIGraphicsPushContext and draw the text via NSString. This gives me access to the graphical memory, which I can push to openGl as a texture.

Would 1 or 3 work in a similar way? 2 wouldn't work as we need IOS5 support. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Core Text (number 1) would probably work better, if I understand your constraints correctly. You would want to hang onto a reference to your `CTFrame`. When the user taps a point, you call `CTFrameGetLines()` to get an array of `CTLineRef` objects. For each line, you call `CTLineGetStringIndexForPosition()`, which takes a CGPoint as an argument then does what its method signature sounds like.

Comment: Bear in mind that Core Text object coordinates are flipped on iOS. CGPointZero is at the bottom left of a view.

Comment: The reason you would want to query more than one `CTLineRef` for `CTLineGetStringIndexForPosition()` is that you can apply some heuristics to the results. Perhaps the user tapped *nearby* something tappable, but not directly on it. You could get the tapped character indexes from lines above and below the actual tapped point to help correct user finger error.

Comment: As for pushing a texture to OpenGL, since all the CoreText drawing is happening in a Core Graphics context, you should be able to do pretty much anything you like with the context after drawing is finished.

Comment: After a lot of code, I managed to get this working using Core Text. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It takes a shocking amount of code to use Core Text. Especially surprising since I hear it's less code than the API it replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you use:

```
NSUInteger count = [string length];
CGFloat widths[length];
for(int i=0; i<count; ++i) {
  widths[i] = [string sizeWithFont:font forWidth:10000 lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeWordWrap].width;
}
```

and then find the spot by walking this array

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the text rendered will be over multiple lines, with line breaks added in the most appropriate place by the render function.

Comment: @OliverHume can you use an iOS7 solution? All the iOS6 and earlier methods to compute sizes are now deprecated, and replaced by a new one, in 7.